# how to add form field on click inside ngfor angular 5

Tags: angular

https://angular-tpw9sy.stackblitz.io

Need to add two form fields to the form dynamically. not getting where to start.
I developed a replica of my app.
U can find the link of the replica above.

Answer (score 0):

if you has a formArray simply use a push

```
(this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray).push(
  this.fb.group({
    company:"123"
  })
);
```

if you want add a control in a Reactive Form you can do

```
this.myForm=this.fb.group({
  ...this.myForm.controls,
  newControl:this.fb.control("newControl")
})
```

and if you want to add some controls to an element of Formarray you can do

```
index=0;
let rowArray:FormGroup=(this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray)
     .at(index) as FormGroup;
let newRowArray=this.fb.group({
      ...rowArray.controls,
      newControl:this.fb.control("newControl")
  });

(this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray).controls[index]=newRowArray;
this.myForm=this.fb.group({
  ...this.myForm.controls,
  myArray:this.fb.array((this.myForm.get('myArray') as FormArray).controls)
}
)
```

where myForm is your form an you have in constructor

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
```